# Proving the First Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}$Let $\phi:  G \rightarrow H$ be homomorphic.  We're asked to show that the quotient group $G/\ker\phi$ is isomorphic to $\im\phi$.  I am trying to do it without the universal property of quotient because my instructor never covered it.

Let $\pi:  G/\ker\phi \rightarrow \im\phi$ be defined by $\pi(g\ker\phi) = \phi(g)$.  I am comfortable with my proof that $\pi$ is well-defined and homomorphic.  The harder part is the one-to-one correspondence part.

By definition of an image, $\phi:  G \rightarrow \im\phi$ is onto.  Now, assume that $\pi:  G/\ker\phi \rightarrow \im\phi$ is not onto; there is an element, $x \in \im\phi$, such that $\pi(g\ker\phi) \neq x$ for all $g\ker\phi \in G\ker\phi$.  But $G\ker\phi = \{ \space g\ker\phi \space | \space g \in G \}$.  So I just found one element in $\im\phi$, $x = \phi(g_x)$ with $g_x \in G$ but $g_x\ker\phi \notin G\ker\phi$, which is a contradiction.  $\pi$ is onto.

To show that $\pi$ is one-to-one, show that $\ker\pi = \{\ker\phi\}$, where $\ker\phi$ is the identity element in $G/\ker\phi$.  By defintion, $\ker\pi = \{ \space g\ker\phi \space | \space \pi(g\ker\phi) = 1_H\}$.  However, since $\pi(g\ker\phi) = \phi(g) = 1_H$, $g \in \ker\phi$.  As a result, $\ker\pi = \{\ker\phi\} \leftrightarrow \pi$ is one-to-one.

I did not feel 100% confident because $g\ker\phi$ is a set of elements in $G$, and the $g$ in $g\ker\phi$ may not be unique.  But on the other hand, $\pi$ is well-defined.  So, am I allowed say "$\pi$ unplugs the $g$ from $g\ker\phi$ and put it into $\phi$?

In the second part, $\{\ker\phi\}, \ker\phi$ are two different kinds of sets.  So, I cannot use left- and right- inclusions.  How do I know that I did not leave out or include an element by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

$\pi : G/ \ker \phi \rightarrow im(\phi)$ is $1$-$1$:  if $\pi(\bar{x}) = \pi(\bar{y})$, then $\phi(x) = \phi(y) \implies \phi(x y^{-1}) = 1 \implies xy^{-1} \in \ker \phi \implies \bar{x} = \bar{y}$ as $x (\ker \phi) = y (\ker \phi) \iff x y^{-1} \in \ker \phi$.